# Output redirection is not working with top piped to grep

Tags: centos, pipe, io-redirection, top

When I run this command in Linux:

```
$ top -b -d 20 | grep "load average" -A 20 > top.log
```

top.log is always empty.

But when I run this command:

```
$ top -b -d 20 | grep "load average" -A 20 | tee top.log
```

then top.log has contents.

If I don't want to use `tee` (because I don't want the output to be displayed onto the console), how do I correct the first command so that top.log is updated?

My machine uses CentOS Linux 7 (Core).

Comment: weird. In my Cento7 machine, both commands work well.

Comment: if you want only load average, why not use `uptime` ?

Comment: @Archemar What is the `-A` option of `grep` for?

Comment: @Archemar @UncleBilly, i'm using a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42911402/5762785) for limiting the amount of entries returned by `top`.

Comment: @UncleBilly Ah, yes that is the catch ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `--line-buffered` option of `grep` (since your question is tagged "centos", you're most certainly using GNU grep).

By default, `grep` will only use line buffering when the output is a terminal (just like stdio functions: printf, puts, etc). The `--line-buffered` option is overriding that. GNU coreutils also has a stdbuf(1) wrapper that should work with any dynamically linked program which is using stdio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cat /proc/loadavg` at intervals. Why pull it from `top`? It is intended for active monitoring (mostly), and will always use more resources than a fast read of `loadavg`. For the process listing, just use `ps`, and sort with the `—sort` flag. E.g.

`( while true ; do cat /proc/loadavg ; ps -aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 20 ; sleep 3 ; done ; ) | pipe ...`

or

`( while true ; do cat /proc/loadavg ; ps -Ao user,uid,pid,comm,pcpu,tty —sort=-pcpu —no-headers | head -n 20 ; sleep 3 ; done ; ) | pipe ...`